# Font will only change one time when running an app

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to change the font of a label in the code. If I run the application it will set the font as specified in the code but if I run it again without restarting, the font will not change on any subsequent runs.

```
.Flaps.Text = items(14)
If .Flaps.Text <> "15" Then
   .Flaps.Font = New Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 36.25,FontStyle.Bold)
   .Flaps.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 191, 0)
Else
   .Flaps.ForeColor = Color.Cyan
   .Flaps.Font = New Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", 26.25,FontStyle.Bold)
End If
```

If I run the app the first time and the flaps value is not 15 it will set the font and color accordingly, but when I run it again without restarting, it will keep the font size but the color will change. Any advice on how to remedy this situation.

Comment: Did you add a [breakpoint](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/debugging) in your code, executing rows per rows, in order to see where is the problem?

Comment: Yes I did. When I run through the code, it actually shows that the font is the correct size for the label, but it does not display the correct size on the app itself.

Comment: "if I run it again without restarting" - does part of code (not designer code) create and add the `Flaps` label to the Form?  If so, is that code possibly adding a second label in the same position?

Comment: I am working with someone else code, and there is a lot of code to go through but I know they created the page using the designer. I do not think there is another label being created because the color changes with each iteration and the font does not revert to the font that is set on the design page.